# why the city of my current location is null in android studio?

Tags: java, android, location

hi I made a simple app that gets current location with gps and shows the current city but when I run it, it shows latitude and longitude correctly but returns city  as null

```
Location mLastLocation = locationResult.getLastLocation();
lat = mLastLocation.getLatitude() + "";
lon = mLastLocation.getLongitude() + "";
Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(MLocationListener.this, Locale.getDefault());

List<Address> addresses;
try {
    addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude(), 1);
    if (addresses.size() > 0) {
        // Log.d("city", addresses.get(0).getLocality());
        String cityName = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
        //Toast.makeText(MLocationListener.this, cityName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: From where do you get city name?

Comment: please take a loot at my solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
Google map = googleMap;
this.map = googleMap;
this.map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
this.map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
this.map.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
this.map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
this.map.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
this.map.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);
String s = "New York"; 
List<Address> addressList = null;
if(s!=null){ 
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder( ); //inside put "getActivity()" or "this"
    try{
        addressList=geocoder.getFromLocationName(s, 1);
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Address address = addressList.get(0);
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(s));
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10));
}
```

Is good to put this type of solution inside a class which implements `OnMapReadyCallback`, inside the method `OnMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)`

Hope this can help you